# How to show Civicrm Event in fullcalendar?

Tags: drupal

In drupal view i want to show civicrm events and selecting display format is Fullcalendar ....Error is showing Display "Page" requires at least one date field."  I am taking fullcalendar module version 7.x-2.0 and FullCalendar jQuery plugin version 1.5.0. I am not getting any solutions from anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

There was an Extension built that says it integrates with Drupal FullCalendar
https://civicrm.org/extensions/event-calendar-extension
but it doesn't show a release version for civi since 4.4

Otherwise if you are wanting to do this directly with Drupal Views have you tried enabling the [CiviCRM Entity module](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity) to see if that can help you?

And there is now a sample View that works with 4.6 with civicrm_entity enabled [here](http://www.fuzion.co.nz/blogs/simple-view-showing-civi-events)

Comment: Note, with CiviCRM Entities 2.x version you can add a View via the 'add from template' option.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read this issue and fix here:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1888812

In general for drupal modules and drupal specific errors, asking on the drupal forums / issue queue might be a better solution

Comment: I think civicrm has a problem with integration in  drupal fullcalendar .... No where i did not solutions for it.

Comment: No help from civicrm forum till now ......